# Appending Incorrect Value in For-Loop and If-Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, append

I'm writing a for-loop to create a list of characters ('e' for edible, 'p' for poisonous) from a binary list (1 corresponding to 'p', and 0 corresponding to 'e'). When I try to do this, everyone gets evaluated to 'e'.

```
for val in predictions:
  if predictions[val] == 1:
      toAnswer.append('p')
  else:
      toAnswer.append('e')
```

I'm expecting a mix of 'p' and 'e', but when I print out my toAnswer list, it's filled entirely with 'e's. I also printed out my predictions list and it showed a mixture of 1s and 0s. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should say if val ==1 instead of predictions[val].

Comment: Thank you!! This fixed the issue! I'm so used to Java that my Python still needs work!

Comment: `for` in Python is similar to a for each loop in Java.